# How do I generate client libraries of my Googe App Engine project (written in Python) to be included in Android Application

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I have an android application which needs to communicate with Endpoints API. I have hosted this API in http://ccpushtest.appspot.com.

How do I generate the client libraries to include in my application?

The documentation from Google - I can barely understand (I'm a beginner)

Comment: tell us exactly where in the google instruxtions you are stuck and what have you tried so far

Comment: Hi John, you really need to do some learning on your own so that you can a specific question.

Comment: endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -bs desired_client_bundle Modals.MyApi

I am getting ServerRequestException (500) running above command on terminal.